# IConfiguration in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

`IConfiguration` is automatically added in `Startup.ca`

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        conf = configuration;
    }
```

similarly we can add it to controllers with dependency injection. Now thats an interface, but we can still use its methods like a class(like `conf.GetSection` as an example). Where and how is the inherited class setup for `IConfiguration` that we can use its methods that return a value?

Comment: I think you want appSettings.json if I recall correctly

Comment: i know what `cong.GetSection` does. i just dont understand how an interface gets that value. what class(thats hooked up to the interface) is being used here when we have an interface for dependency injection?

Comment: Check the docs and see what classes are derived from that interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: im asking where this implementation happens behind the scene

Comment: this is the job of the framework, usually no one knows until he reads the source code (which is public on Github). For most developers (even professionals) and in most scenarios, we usually don't need to care about that. So it's a bit strange for you to want to know about that. We have a lot of other things to focus on instead. Of course when it comes to a good reason for you to have to know that, it then makes sense.

Comment: the bootstrap creates a dedicated `IServiceProvider` for the host building process, here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/WebHostBuilder.cs#L283 is where it registers an instance of `IConfiguration` which later can be injected into `Startup`'s constructor. I must agree that the whole logic is very complicated, involving many classes. Sometimes we really need to read it, but sometimes it's not very necessary (will spend a lot of time).

Answer (score 0):

As King King's comments, the IConfiguration is a service which is injected by default when calling the Build method in the program.cs.  You could find it call the [BuildCommonServices method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/WebHostBuilder.cs) which will inject the  IConfiguration service. The IConfiguration service will be created by using the IConfigurationBuilder's build method. If you want to know how the DI works in the asp.net core, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Some part of the WebHostBuilder class.

```
public IWebHost Build()
    {
      if (this._webHostBuilt)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.WebHostBuilder_SingleInstance);
      this._webHostBuilt = true;
      AggregateException hostingStartupErrors;
      IServiceCollection serviceCollection1 = this.BuildCommonServices(out hostingStartupErrors);
      IServiceCollection serviceCollection2 = serviceCollection1.Clone();
      IServiceProvider providerFromFactory = GetProviderFromFactory(serviceCollection1);
      .....

　　　　WebHost webHost = new WebHost(serviceCollection2, providerFromFactory, this._options, this._config, hostingStartupErrors);
      try
      {
        webHost.Initialize();
        return (IWebHost) webHost;
      }
      catch
      {
        webHost.Dispose();
        throw;
      }

    IServiceProvider GetProviderFromFactory(IServiceCollection collection)
      {
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection> service = ((IServiceProvider) serviceProvider).GetService<IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>>();
        if (service == null)
          return (IServiceProvider) serviceProvider;
        using (serviceProvider)
          return service.CreateServiceProvider(service.CreateBuilder(collection));
      }
    }
```